# Java Split string into individual words for Pig Latin translator

Tags: java, string

I have a one word Pig Latin translator, and I need it to

- Translate a string with multiple words
- Capitalize appropriately
- Punctuate correctly (non-letter characters. i.e. astah, = astahay, not astah,ay)

The word/string I am using to test this is "Astah la vista, baby." whose output should be "Astahay alay istavay, abybay."

This code only translates one word strings correctly, and does not capitalize/punctuate correctly. 
My program uses 3 methods, input(), pigLatinator(), and display() to input the string, translate, and display the translation.
With this structure, what could I change/add to make this program work closer to the way I would like it? I've looked at using String.split("\\s") but I don't understand how to implement it.

## input Method:

```
    public String input(){
    System.out.println("Please enter your string.");
    System.out.print("String: ");
    originalString = keyboard.nextLine();
    originalString = originalString.toLowerCase(); //String.toLowerCase() to prevent error on line 41 (if() statement)

    return originalString;
}
```

## pigLatinator Method:

```
    public String pigLatinator(String originalString){
    if(originalString.startsWith("a") || originalString.startsWith("e") || originalString.startsWith("i") || originalString.startsWith("o") || originalString.startsWith("u")){
        pigString = originalString + "ay";
    }else{
        pigString = originalString.substring(1) + originalString.charAt(0) + "ay";
    }

    return pigString;
}
```

## display Method:

```
public void display(){
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Original string: " +originalString);
    System.out.println("Translation: " +pigString);
}
```

## Outputs:

### Output 1:

```
Please enter your string.
String: astah

Original string: astah
Translation: astahay
```

Works

### Output 2:

```
Please enter your string.
String: Astah

Original string: astah
Translation: astahay
```

### Output 3:

```
Please enter your string.
String: astah,

Original string: astah,
Translation: astah,ay
```

### Output 4:

```
Please enter your string.
String: Astah la vista, baby.

Original string: astah la vista, baby.
Translation: astah la vista, baby.ay
```

Comment: You can `split(" ")` your `Original string` on newline character and then make the program go through each of the individual words in the array as it does for a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your input sentence into individual words using the `String.split` function. That's the first step, something like this:

```
String[] words = originalString.split(" ");
String[] pigWords;
```

Once you've done that, you can loop over each word to change it:

```
pigWords = new String[words.length];
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    pigWords[i] = pigLatinator(words[i])
```

Then, modify your pigLatinator to check if the end of the word has a punctuation mark, and insert "ay" before that punctuation mark:

```
int index = originalString.length() -1;
char lastChar = originalString.charAt(index);
if (char == "." || char == ",")
    String pigString = originalString.substring(0,index) + "ay" + originalString.charAt(index);
```

Since your `PigLatin` class is a separate class to where your main is, you should be able to do something like this:

```
class PigLatin
{
    String originalString = "", pigString = "";

    public void input() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your string.");
        System.out.print("String: ");
        originalString = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    }

    private String pigLatinator(String word)
    {
        String output = "";
        int index = word.length() -1;
        char lastChar = word.charAt(index);

        if(word.startsWith("a") || word.startsWith("e") || word.startsWith("i") || word.startsWith("o") || word.startsWith("u"))
        {
            if (char == '.' || char == ',' || char == '!')
                output = word.substring(0,index) + "ay" + word.charAt(index);
            else
                output = word + "ay";
        }
        else
        {
            if (char == '.' || char == ',' || char == '!')
                output = word.substring(1,index) + word.charAt(0) + "ay" + word.charAt(index);
            else
                output = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0) + "ay";
        }

        return output;
    }

    public void translate()
    {
        String[] words = originalString.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            pigString += pigLatinator(words[i]) + " ";
        }
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Original string: " +originalString);
        System.out.println("Translation: " +pigString);
    }
}
```

Then, inside your `main` function, declare a new `PigLatin` object, and call the appropriate functions:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PigLatin myPigLatin = new PigLatin();
    myPigLatin.input();
    myPigLatin.translate();
    myPigLatin.display();
}
```

This code is untested, but it should work, it's simple enough.

Comment: I'm assuming the arrays are instance variables? I am inexperienced with arrays. When I put them in it compiles however when my program is run there is an error on the line containing String[] words = originalString.split(" ") with error Java.lang.NullPointerException : null. Also, would the for loop go inside the input() method? How exactly would I modify my pigLatinator() method, would I put the additions before the loop I already have?

Comment: You need to call that line after you declare and initialize `originalString` with input from the user, otherwise, the string doesn't contain anything, and will cause a `NullPointerException`

Comment: in fact, since your `input` function returns a string, you can change it to `String[] words = input().split(" ");` which will call the input function for you and automatically split the words into the array. Although doing that you won't have the original input stored in a whole string.

Comment: Okay, where would I initialize `String[] pigWords` and add in the `for` loop? Inside `input()` seems pointless when there are no `pigWords` to be added and `words` is not declared inside `pigLatinator()`?

Comment: You would implement it in the main function, which is outside your `input` function

Comment: My `main()` method is inside a seperate class, is there a way to keep the declaration inside my `pigLatin()` class?